# Calculating count on same table based on condition

Tags: sql-server, count

So I need to calculate the amount of Clients who's LastName start with the same letter, then use that count as part of an Reference number.

I.e. something like this:

```
declare @AmountOfSimilarSurnames int;
set @AmountOfSimilarSurnames = (...)

declare @Ref nvarchar(100);
set @Ref = 'CLT00' + @AmountOfSimilarSurnames
```

I need help setting that `AmountOfSimilarSurnames`

So far I got this but it is working:

```
select COUNT(*) FROM Client c1
join Client c2 on RIGHT(c1.Client_LName,1) = RIGHT(c2.Client_LName,1)
```

Comment: `RIGHT` will compare the last character rather than the first so you probably want to use `LEFT` instead. This is a many-to-many join so you will count the same name more than once when more than one name starts with the same character. Consider using `EXISTS` rather than `JOIN`. This is an odd requirement to use the count in a reference number since the count will change as clients are inserted, updated, or removed.

Comment: Aaah I see. Yeah the idea behind the count is to give the user 'n user facing reference, it's arbitrary for the back end but it's client require.

Comment: Also, how would that Exists query look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example using `RIGHT` (starting character) and `EXISTS` (so that matching names are counted only once).

```
DECLARE @Ref nvarchar(100) = 'CLT00'
    + CAST(
        (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM Client c1
        WHERE EXISTS(
            SELECT 1
            FROM Client c2
            WHERE
                LEFT(c1.Client_LName,1) = LEFT(c2.Client_LName,1)
            )
        ) AS varchar(10));
```